# Why does Google Tag Manager not include tags on certain pages?

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have an issue that on certain pages of my website no tags are included in the GTM container. The debugger shows: "There are no tags in the container." I'm trying now for weeks to find the solution but no chance. I would really appreciate any ideas!

I have included for example the Google Universal code on all pages:
**url matches RegEx .***

Usually on the start page and some other pages no tags are included:
**http://www.ailolaquito.com**

On other pages like this the tags usually are included:
**http://www.ailolaquito.com/en/activities/spanish-and-dancing**

When I use the GTM Preview and Debugger tool it first shows above message and when I open the *Data Layer* tab and switch back to the *Tags* tab, suddenly all tags are shown as they should. Maybe there is a conflict (JavaScript?) on some pages.

What I noticed is that on all pages where the tags are not included the HTML code in the source view of Safari looks compressed:
[image: Bad Code]

While on pages where the tags are properly shown the html source looks nice:
[image: Nice Code]

Probably it's related with this. However I don't understand why the source code is compressed on some pages. They are all based on the same layout templates.

Any ideas or help would be appreciated. I really would like to solve the issue.

Thanks a lot!

Philip

P.S.: Here are some more screenshots:

[image: GTM Tags]
[image: GTM Container OK]
[image: GTM Container not OK]

Comment: I see GTM on the homepage - have you already resolved the problem ?

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. No, the problem isn't solved. I see the GTM code, too, but that's not the issue. The issue is that the tags (e.g. Google Analytics) which should be included on any page are not shown in the source code. I will add to my original post a screenshot with all tags in my container.

Comment: I mean I see GTM, Analytics and Remarketing via the Google Tag inspector (not just that the GTM code is implemented).

Comment: I'm not sure which browser you are using. I tested in Safari 6.1.5
and Chrome Version 43.0.2357.130 (64-bit) on Mac OS X. Sometimes I also see all tags but sometimes not. It doesn't depend on the page. Sometimes on the start page all tags from the container are included and sometimes not. In FireFox 37.0.2 for example I couldn't reproduce the issue.

Comment: Chrome on Ubuntu and Chrome on Windows 7. I will check this later this evening with a Mac (maybe there is some weird local problem on your end of the network).

Comment: Works for me both in Chrome and Safari on OSX, too.

Comment: Sorry for not replying any more and many thanks for testing. Maybe you use a later Safari version. I assume that the issue is connected to certain browser versions based on Webkit (Chrome & Safari) because in FireFox it works for me fine, too. Or maybe it's my own local setup. I think I need to test more on different systems to find out. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

for the answer see https://plus.google.com/102446957955231069158/posts/FetKoAh2JrD "there is a race condition that we are currently hunting down that when the debug script is cached you can see the no tags message. But if you click on any of the events and you can see what fired. Once you navigate to an event the summary tab will display correctly again. You can also force refresh the page which seams to fix this also." by Michael Philpott